# I want to change an email address in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word I would like to search the active document for @yahoo.com and replace all instances with newName@gmail.com. When I use the *@yahoo.com to find it the replace command erases all of the document before the @yahoo.com

```
    Sub kiffin()
         With Selection.Find
         .ClearFormatting
         .MatchWildcards = True
         .Text = "*@yahoo.com"
         .Replacement.ClearFormatting
         .Replacement.Text = "newName@gmail.com"
         .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
           Wrap:=wdFindContinue
       End With

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard `*` is clearly too greedy in this case, and the limited wildcard/regex support available in Word's Find functionality may not be suited for identifying individual email addresses. (Note: Word, nor RegEx is an expertise of mine).

If the email addresses in the Word Document are given as Hyperlinks, this can be accomplished by looping over the `Hyperlinks` collection, and checking the `TextToDisplay` for the `"@yahoo.com"` domain.

```
Sub ReplaceEmailHyperlinks()

Dim newemail as String
Dim h As Hyperlink

newemail = "NewEmail@gmail.com"

For Each h In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    If h.TextToDisplay Like "*@yahoo.com" Then
        h.TextToDisplay = newemail
        h.Address = "mailto:" & newemail
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Works great!!